# Website header is cut off

Tags: css, center, centering

Can anybody shine light onto why the header is beign cut off on a monitor with 1366x768 resolution? [Header is cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3hu4.jpg). Ideally, this should look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYHuy.jpg). Testing the site with screenfly tool has [a bit better result](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//baltikcom.com/&w=1366&h=768&a=1), but the header is cut nonetheless.

Is this due to a cotnent wrapper with translate properties that is supposed to center the site from all 4 sides of the monitor?

```
.cn {
display: flex; 
justify-content: center; 
align-items: center; }

.inner {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
width: 1301px;
height: 890px;
}
```

Comment: CSS is not really my thing...but margin is worth trying, or was it padding...?

Comment: Just tried. If I change the margin, things do look better for the 1366x768 screens, but all other resolutions are brought down as well. That way the content has an even wider gap than it was. However, thanks.

Comment: why are you making your flex item `position: absolute;`? I would remove the `position`,`top`,`left`, and `transform` from your `.inner` and let the flexbox do its job

Comment: Do you have more code that we can use to replicate? Images are helpful within reason, but including the HTML and CSS we'll have a better chance to help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother anyone with this. I've found a fix. I changed the resolution for @media screen and (min-width: 1600px)

Changed from 1301px to 1600px and that solved it.